# Highlight syntax in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contenteditable div I want users to type in. When users type inside the box with onkeyup, I activate a function that changes the color of certain characters:

```
var lTags = fixedCode.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<span style='color:gold;'>&lt;</span>");
var rTags = lTags.replace(/&gt;/gi, "<span style='color:gold'>&gt;</span>");
fixedCode.innerHTML = rTags;
```

What this code does is it takes every < sign and every > sign and turns it into a gold color. However, when I do this, I am no longer able to type words into the contenteditable box since the box refreshes itself every time I press a key.

```js
function checkIt(code) {
   var fixedCode = document.getElementById(code);
   var lTags = fixedCode.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<span style='color:gold;'>&lt;</span>");
   var rTags = lTags.replace(/&gt;/gi, "<span style='color:gold'>&gt;</span>");
   fixedCode.innerHTML = rTags;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="checkIt(this.id);">See for yourself</div>
```

To see for yourself, try typing any HTML tag in the box.
First of all, why does it change the color of the left `<` of a tag but not the right part of the tag `>`? And how can I actually type inside the box without deleting the color-changing stuff. I've seen similar questions, but the answers were Jquery. ***I do not want to use JQUERY!***

Comment: The problem with innerhtml is that it has to replace everything in the textbox. I need a way around this while also being able to change the tags and update the contenteditable box.

Comment: ew, please format your code nicely

Comment: Is there someway to tell if < or > has been added to the code and only change it IF that happens?

Comment: First of all, I need to know whether or not what I'm asking is possible to do...

Comment: If you didn't understand what I'm asking for in the question, see one of my comments on @takethefake's answer (explains what I need). [Comment Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884969/replacing-content-in-contenteditable-box-while-typing?answertab=active#comment70952724_41885142)

Comment: The answer to your first question is that you aren't using the right entity code. It should be `&gt;` not `&rt;`

Comment: Oh, silly me! Thanks, @KodosJohnson. I'll modify my question to have that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was too lazy to go *hardcore* with JavaScript and one idea that popped my mind was to use

- two overlaying DIV elements
- the overlaying **contenteditable** has **transparent text** but **visible caret**!
- the underlaying DIV is the one that shows the colorful syntax highlighted content

**PROS**

- The pros about this technique is that you always keep (in the contenteditable DIV) the **unchanged content in its original state**.

**CONS**

- On every keystroke we parse all over again the same content, and as it gets bigger it might be a performance killer as your replacement list grows `O(n)`

For a beautiful read on **optimization** head to [VSCode Optimizations in Syntax Highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations)

#### Basic example:

```js
const highLite = (el) => {
  el.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = el.innerHTML
     .replace(/(&lt;|&gt;)/g, "<span class='hl_angled'>$1</span>")
     .replace(/(\{|\})/g, "<span class='hl_curly'>$1</span>");
};

document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("input", () => highLite(el));
  highLite(el);
});
```

```css
body{ margin:0; font:14px/1 sans-serif; }

/*scrollbar*/
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 8px; height: 8px; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background: transparent; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #0bf; border-radius: 1rem; }

.highLite{
  border: 1px solid #888;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto; 
  height: 9rem; /* set as desired */
}

.highLite_colors,
.highLite_editable {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: calc(100% - 2rem);
}

/* THE UNDERLAYING ONE WITH COLORS */
.highLite_colors {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  user-select: none;
}

/* THE OVERLAYING CONTENTEDITABLE WITH TRANSPARENT TEXT */
.highLite_editable {
  position: relative;
  color: transparent; /* Make text invisible */
  caret-color: black; /* But keep caret visible */
}
.highLite_editable:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.hl_angled{ color: turquoise; }
.hl_curly{ color: fuchsia; }
```

```html
Try to type some angled &lt; &gt; or curly { } brackets
<div class="highLite">
  <div class="highLite_colors">Type &lt;here&gt; {something}</div>
  <div class="highLite_editable" contenteditable>Type &lt;here&gt; {something}</div>
</div>
```

#### Advanced example:

(*use at your own risk this was my coffee-time playground*)

```js
const lang = {
  js: {
    equa: /(\b=\b)/g,
    quot: /((&#39;.*?&#39;)|(&#34;.*?&#34;)|(".*?(?<!\\)")|('.*?(?<!\\)')|`)/g,
    comm: /((\/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+\/)|(\/\/.*))/g,
    logi: /(%=|%|\-|\+|\*|&amp;{1,2}|\|{1,2}|&lt;=|&gt;=|&lt;|&gt;|!={1,2}|={2,3})/g,
    numb: /(\d+(\.\d+)?(e\d+)?)/g,
    func: /(?<=^|\s*)(async|await|console|alert|Math|Object|Array|String|class(?!\s*\=)|function)(?=\b)/g,
    decl: /(?<=^|\s*)(var|let|const)/g,
    pare: /(\(|\))/g,
    squa: /(\[|\])/g,
    curl: /(\{|\})/g,
  },
  html: {
    tags: /(?<=&lt;(?:\/)?)(\w+)(?=\s|\&gt;)/g,
    // Props order matters! Here I rely on "tags"
    // being already applied in the previous iteration
    angl: /(&lt;\/?|&gt;)/g,
    attr: /((?<=<i class=html_tags>\w+<\/i>)[^<]+)/g,
  }
};

const highLite = el => {
  const dataLang = el.dataset.lang; // Detect "js", "html", "py", "bash", ...
  const langObj = lang[dataLang]; // Extract object from lang regexes dictionary
  let html = el.innerHTML;
  Object.keys(langObj).forEach(function(key) {
    html = html.replace(langObj[key], `<i class=${dataLang}_${key}>$1</i>`);
  });
  el.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = html; // Finally, show highlights!
};

const editors = document.querySelectorAll(".highLite_editable");
editors.forEach(el => {
  el.contentEditable = true;
  el.spellcheck = false;
  el.autocorrect = "off";
  el.autocapitalize = "off";
  el.addEventListener("input", () => highLite(el));
  highLite(el); // Init!
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; box-sizing: boder-box;}

/*scrollbar*/
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 8px; height: 8px; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); border-radius: 0px; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); border-radius: 1rem; }

body {
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
  background: hsl(220, 16%, 16%);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#editor {
  display: flex;
}

h2 {
  padding: 16px 0;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.highLite {
  position: relative;
  background: hsl(220, 16%, 14%);
  height: 9rem;      /* set as desired */
  overflow: auto;
}

.highLite_colors,
.highLite_editable {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: calc(100% - 2rem);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
}

/* THE OVERLAYING CONTENTEDITABLE WITH TRANSPARENT TEXT */
.highLite_editable {
  position: relative;
  color: transparent; /* Make text invisible */
  caret-color: hsl( 50, 75%, 70%); /* But keep caret visible */
}
.highLite_editable:focus {
  outline: 1px solid hsl(220, 16%, 19%);
}
.highLite_editable::selection {
  background: hsla( 0, 0%, 90%, 0.2);
}

/* THE UNDERLAYING ONE WITH HIGHLIGHT COLORS */
.highLite_colors {
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
}

.highLite_colors i {
  font-style: normal;
}

/* JS */
i.js_quot { color: hsl( 50, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_decl { color: hsl(200, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_func { color: hsl(300, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_pare { color: hsl(210, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_squa { color: hsl(230, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_curl { color: hsl(250, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_numb { color: hsl(100, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_logi { color: hsl(200, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_equa { color: hsl(200, 75%, 70%); }
i.js_comm { color: hsl(200, 10%, 45%); font-style: italic; }
i.js_comm > * { color: inherit; }

/* HTML */
i.html_angl { color: hsl(200, 10%, 45%); }
i.html_tags { color: hsl(  0, 75%, 70%); }
i.html_attr { color: hsl(200, 74%, 70%); }
```

```html
<h2>HTML</h2>
<div class="highLite">
    <div class="highLite_colors"></div>
    <div class="highLite_editable" data-lang="html">&lt;h2 class="head"&gt;
TODO: HTML is for &lt;b&gt;homework&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;/h2&gt;</div>
</div>

<h2>JAVASCRIPT</h2>
<div class="highLite">
    <div class="highLite_colors"></div>
    <div class="highLite_editable" data-lang="js">// Type some JavaScript here

const arr = ["high", 'light'];
let n = 2.1 * 3;
if (n &lt; 10) {
  console.log(`${n} is &lt;&#61; than 10`);
}
function casual(str) {
  str = str || "non\"sense";
  alert("Just a casual"+ str +", still many TODOs");
}
casual (arr.join('') +" idea!");

/**
* The code is a proof of concept and far from
* perfect. You should never use regex but create or use a parser.
* Meanwhile, play with it and improve it!
*/</div>
</div>
```

**TODO**
given this basic idea, some TODO I left for the reader:

- instead of using Regex, use or create a proper **parser** to perform lexical analysis (tokenization) or syntactic analysis (parsing) for the specific languages you want to support in your syntax highlighter.

Comment: Wow that is pretty nice.

Comment: I'm wondering, how did you handle one bug that the OP didn't mention. That is, to stop replacing `<` characters once they have been wrapped? I don't see how you solve that but it seems like it is fixed in your code.

Comment: @KodosJohnson (eagle eyes!) that's because I don't touch the content of the element the user actually types in :) So the sugar key is that you always have a clean unchanged version (and that's the content of the contenteditable DIV)

Comment: This is very nice! :)

Comment: This is the answer, thank you @RokoC.Buljan. It's a solution that is short, clean, and easy to understand. Better than all the complicated Regexp stuff.

Comment: Now all I have to do is use this to replace other code-stuff as well. I might actually make a great code editor!! :D

Comment: This wonderful...easy and clean...thank u so much..u saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

Never. Parse. HTML. With. Regex.

Just walk the DOM and split nodes where necessary.

```js
function wrap(textNode, str, cName) {
  var pos = textNode.nodeValue.indexOf(str);
  if (pos < 0) return false;
  var newNode = textNode.splitText(pos);
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = cName;
  textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, newNode);
  newNode.splitText(str.length);
  span.appendChild(newNode);
  return true;
}
function checkIt() {
  for (var i=0; i<this.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    var node = this.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      if (wrap(node, '<', 'less-than')) ++i;
      if (wrap(node, '>', 'greater-than')) ++i;
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      checkIt.call(node);
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('input', checkIt);
```

```css
.less-than, .greater-than {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" contenteditable="true">See for yourself</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What if `&gt;` is used in an attribute value? Never. Parse. HTML. With. Regex.

Comment: You mean like in `data-foo="&lt;bar&gt;"`? (Copy-paste this into my example...)

Comment: The problem with this is once you type > or < all the other characters after that are also the gold color...

Comment: @IamGuest Argh, that's Chrome's fault, it works like a charm on Firefox.

Comment: @Oriol, the thing is, since I am creating a code editor, I need my code to be cross-browser (supported in most major browsers). This code works well on Firefox and IE, but it doesn't work in Chrome (many people use Chrome). EDIT: To clarify, it works, but it changes the color of everything after it as well. It is a nice idea, though. This would've been the answer if it worked in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have syntax highlighting in a contenteditable div, because the colors will get mixed up. But you can make a contenteditable div AND a normal div which will show the colors and place them in the same position. (Believe me, there are no external js files. See the code below.)

```js
function syntaxHighlight(contentEditableElement, mode) {
contentEditableElement.style.left = contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.style.left = 0;
contentEditableElement.style.top = contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.style.top = 0;
contentEditableElement.style.right = contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.style.right = 0;
contentEditableElement.style.bottom = contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.style.bottom = 0;
contentEditableElement.style.position = "relative";
contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.style.position = "absolute";
contentEditableElement.style.webkitTextFillColor = "transparent";
contentEditableElement.parentElement.style.position = "relative";
if (mode == "html") {
contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = htmlMode(contentEditableElement.innerHTML);
}
if (mode == "css") {
contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = cssMode(contentEditableElement.innerHTML);
}
if (mode == "javascript") {
contentEditableElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = jsMode(contentEditableElement.innerHTML);
}

function extract(str, start, end, func, repl) {
var s, e, d = "", a = [];
while (str.search(start) > -1) {
s = str.search(start);
e = str.indexOf(end, s);
if (e == -1) {e = str.length;}
if (repl) {
a.push(func(str.substring(s, e + (end.length))));
str = str.substring(0, s) + repl + str.substr(e + (end.length));
} else {
d += str.substring(0, s);
d += func(str.substring(s, e + (end.length)));
str = str.substr(e + (end.length));
}
}
this.rest = d + str;
this.arr = a;
}
function htmlMode(txt) {
var rest = txt, done = "", php, comment, angular, startpos, endpos, note, i;
comment = new extract(rest, "&lt;!--", "--&gt;", commentMode, "W3HTMLCOMMENTPOS");
rest = comment.rest;
while (rest.indexOf("&lt;") > -1) {
note = "";
startpos = rest.indexOf("&lt;");
if (rest.substr(startpos, 9).toUpperCase() == "&LT;STYLE") {note = "css";}
if (rest.substr(startpos, 10).toUpperCase() == "&LT;SCRIPT") {note = "javascript";}
endpos = rest.indexOf("&gt;", startpos);
if (endpos == -1) {endpos = rest.length;}
done += rest.substring(0, startpos);
done += tagMode(rest.substring(startpos, endpos + 4));
rest = rest.substr(endpos + 4);
if (note == "css") {
endpos = rest.indexOf("&lt;/style&gt;");
if (endpos > -1) {
done += cssMode(rest.substring(0, endpos));
rest = rest.substr(endpos);
}
}
if (note == "javascript") {
endpos = rest.indexOf("&lt;/script&gt;");
if (endpos > -1) {
done += jsMode(rest.substring(0, endpos));
rest = rest.substr(endpos);
}
}
}
rest = done + rest;
for (i = 0; i < comment.arr.length; i++) {
rest = rest.replace("W3HTMLCOMMENTPOS", comment.arr[i]);
}
return rest;
}
function tagMode(txt) {
var rest = txt, done = "", startpos, endpos, result;
while (rest.search(/(\s|\n)/) > -1) {
startpos = rest.search(/(\s|\n)/);
endpos = rest.indexOf("&gt;");
if (endpos == -1) {endpos = rest.length;}
done += rest.substring(0, startpos);
done += attributeMode(rest.substring(startpos, endpos));
rest = rest.substr(endpos);
}
result = done + rest;
result = "<span class='html-bracket'>&lt;</span>" + result.substring(4);
if (result.substr(result.length - 4, 4) == "&gt;") {
result = result.substring(0, result.length - 4) + "<span class='html-bracket'>&gt;</span>";
}
return "<span class='html-tag'>" + result + "</span>";
}
function attributeMode(txt) {
var rest = txt, done = "", startpos, endpos, singlefnuttpos, doublefnuttpos, spacepos;
while (rest.indexOf("=") > -1) {
endpos = -1;
startpos = rest.indexOf("=");
singlefnuttpos = rest.indexOf("'", startpos);
doublefnuttpos = rest.indexOf('"', startpos);
spacepos = rest.indexOf(" ", startpos + 2);
if (spacepos > -1 && (spacepos < singlefnuttpos || singlefnuttpos == -1) && (spacepos < doublefnuttpos || doublefnuttpos == -1)) {
endpos = rest.indexOf(" ", startpos);
} else if (doublefnuttpos > -1 && (doublefnuttpos < singlefnuttpos || singlefnuttpos == -1) && (doublefnuttpos < spacepos || spacepos == -1)) {
endpos = rest.indexOf('"', rest.indexOf('"', startpos) + 1);
} else if (singlefnuttpos > -1 && (singlefnuttpos < doublefnuttpos || doublefnuttpos == -1) && (singlefnuttpos < spacepos || spacepos == -1)) {
endpos = rest.indexOf("'", rest.indexOf("'", startpos) + 1);
}
if (!endpos || endpos == -1 || endpos < startpos) {endpos = rest.length;}
done += rest.substring(0, startpos);
done += attributeValueMode(rest.substring(startpos, endpos + 1));
rest = rest.substr(endpos + 1);
}
return "<span class='html-attribute'>" + done + rest + "</span>";
}
function attributeValueMode(txt) {
return "<span class='html-attributeValue'>" + txt + "</span>";
}
function commentMode(txt) {
return "<span class='comment'>" + txt + "</span>";
}
function cssMode(txt) {
var rest = txt, done = "", s, e, comment, i, midz, c, cc;
comment = new extract(rest, /\/\*/, "*/", commentMode, "W3CSSCOMMENTPOS");
rest = comment.rest;
while (rest.search("{") > -1) {
s = rest.search("{");
midz = rest.substr(s + 1);
cc = 1;
c = 0;
for (i = 0; i < midz.length; i++) {
if (midz.substr(i, 1) == "{") {cc++; c++}
if (midz.substr(i, 1) == "}") {cc--;}
if (cc == 0) {break;}
}
if (cc != 0) {c = 0;}
e = s;
for (i = 0; i <= c; i++) {
e = rest.indexOf("}", e + 1);
}
if (e == -1) {e = rest.length;}
done += rest.substring(0, s + 1);
done += cssPropertyMode(rest.substring(s + 1, e));
rest = rest.substr(e);
}
rest = done + rest;
rest = rest.replace(/{/g, "<span class='css-delimiter'>{</span>");
rest = rest.replace(/}/g, "<span class='css-delimiter'>}</span>");
for (i = 0; i < comment.arr.length; i++) {
rest = rest.replace("W3CSSCOMMENTPOS", comment.arr[i]);
}
return "<span class='css-selector'>" + rest + "</span>";
}
function cssPropertyMode(txt) {
var rest = txt, done = "", s, e, n, loop;
if (rest.indexOf("{") > -1 ) { return cssMode(rest); }
while (rest.search(":") > -1) {
s = rest.search(":");
loop = true;
n = s;
while (loop == true) {
loop = false;
e = rest.indexOf(";", n);
if (rest.substring(e - 5, e + 1) == "&nbsp;") {
loop = true;
n = e + 1;
}
}
if (e == -1) {e = rest.length;}
done += rest.substring(0, s);
done += cssPropertyValueMode(rest.substring(s, e + 1));
rest = rest.substr(e + 1);
}
return "<span class='css-property'>" + done + rest + "</span>";
}
function cssPropertyValueMode(txt) {
var rest = txt, done = "", s;
rest = "<span class='css-delimeter'>:</span>" + rest.substring(1);
while (rest.search(/!important/i) > -1) {
s = rest.search(/!important/i);
done += rest.substring(0, s);
done += cssImportantMode(rest.substring(s, s + 10));
rest = rest.substr(s + 10);
}
result = done + rest;
if (result.substr(result.length - 1, 1) == ";" && result.substr(result.length - 6, 6) != "&nbsp;" && result.substr(result.length - 4, 4) != "&lt;" && result.substr(result.length - 4, 4) != "&gt;" && result.substr(result.length - 5, 5) != "&amp;") {
result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1) + "<span class='css-delimiter'>;</span>";
}
return "<span class='css-propertyValue'>" + result + "</span>";
}
function cssImportantMode(txt) {
return "<span class='css-important'>" + txt + "</span>";
}
function jsMode(txt) {
var rest = txt, done = "", esc = [], i, cc, tt = "", sfnuttpos, dfnuttpos, compos, comlinepos, keywordpos, numpos, mypos, dotpos, y;
for (i = 0; i < rest.length; i++){
cc = rest.substr(i, 1);
if (cc == "\\") {
esc.push(rest.substr(i, 2));
cc = "W3JSESCAPE";
i++;
}
tt += cc;
}
rest = tt;
y = 1;
while (y == 1) {
sfnuttpos = getPos(rest, "'", "'", jsStringMode);
dfnuttpos = getPos(rest, '"', '"', jsStringMode);
compos = getPos(rest, /\/\*/, "*/", commentMode);
comlinepos = getPos(rest, /\/\//, "\n", commentMode);
numpos = getNumPos(rest, jsNumberMode);
keywordpos = getKeywordPos("js", rest, jsKeywordMode);
dotpos = getDotPos(rest, jsPropertyMode);
if (Math.max(numpos[0], sfnuttpos[0], dfnuttpos[0], compos[0], comlinepos[0], keywordpos[0], dotpos[0]) == -1) {break;}
mypos = getMinPos(numpos, sfnuttpos, dfnuttpos, compos, comlinepos, keywordpos, dotpos);
if (mypos[0] == -1) {break;}
if (mypos[0] > -1) {
done += rest.substring(0, mypos[0]);
done += mypos[2](rest.substring(mypos[0], mypos[1]));
rest = rest.substr(mypos[1]);
}
}
rest = done + rest;
for (i = 0; i < esc.length; i++) {
rest = rest.replace("W3JSESCAPE", esc[i]);
}
return "<span class='javascript'>" + rest + "</span>";
}
function jsStringMode(txt) {
return "<span class='javascript-string'>" + txt + "</span>";
}
function jsKeywordMode(txt) {
return "<span class='javascript-keyword'>" + txt + "</span>";
}
function jsNumberMode(txt) {
return "<span class='javascript-number'>" + txt + "</span>";
}
function jsPropertyMode(txt) {
return "<span class='javascript-property'>" + txt + "</span>";
}
function getDotPos(txt, func) {
var x, i, j, s, e, arr = [".","<", " ", ";", "(", "+", ")", "[", "]", ",", "&", ":", "{", "}", "/" ,"-", "*", "|", "%"];
s = txt.indexOf(".");
if (s > -1) {
x = txt.substr(s + 1);
for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
cc = x[j];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if (cc.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1) {
e = j;
return [s + 1, e + s + 1, func];
}
}
}
}
return [-1, -1, func];
}
function getMinPos() {
var i, arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
if (arguments[i][0] > -1) {
if (arr.length == 0 || arguments[i][0] < arr[0]) {arr = arguments[i];}
}
}
if (arr.length == 0) {arr = arguments[i];}
return arr;
}
function getKeywordPos(typ, txt, func) {
var words, i, pos, rpos = -1, rpos2 = -1, patt;
if (typ == "js") {
words = ["abstract","arguments","boolean","break","byte","case","catch","char","class","const","continue","debugger","default","delete",
"do","double","else","enum","eval","export","extends","false","final","finally","float","for","function","goto","if","implements","import",
"in","instanceof","int","interface","let","long","NaN","native","new","null","package","private","protected","public","return","short","static",
"super","switch","synchronized","this","throw","throws","transient","true","try","typeof","var","void","volatile","while","with","yield"];
}
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
pos = txt.indexOf(words[i]);
if (pos > -1) {
patt = /\W/g;
if (txt.substr(pos + words[i].length,1).match(patt) && txt.substr(pos - 1,1).match(patt)) {
if (pos > -1 && (rpos == -1 || pos < rpos)) {
rpos = pos;
rpos2 = rpos + words[i].length;
}
}
} 
}
return [rpos, rpos2, func];
}
function getPos(txt, start, end, func) {
var s, e;
s = txt.search(start);
e = txt.indexOf(end, s + (end.length));
if (e == -1) {e = txt.length;}
return [s, e + (end.length), func];
}
function getNumPos(txt, func) {
var arr = ["\n", " ", ";", "(", "+", ")", "[", "]", ",", "&", ":", "{", "}", "/" ,"-", "*", "|", "%", "="], i, j, c, startpos = 0, endpos, word;
for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
c = txt.substr(i, arr[j].length);
if (c == arr[j]) {
if (c == "-" && (txt.substr(i - 1, 1) == "e" || txt.substr(i - 1, 1) == "E")) {
continue;
}
endpos = i;
if (startpos < endpos) {
word = txt.substring(startpos, endpos);
if (!isNaN(word)) {return [startpos, endpos, func];}
}
i += arr[j].length;
startpos = i;
i -= 1;
break;
}
}
}
return [-1, -1, func];
}
}

function syncScroll(element1, element2) {
element2.scrollLeft = element1.scrollLeft;
element2.scrollTop = element1.scrollTop;
}

window.onload = function() {
var code = document.getElementById("code");
syntaxHighlight(code, "html");
}
```

```css
.html-bracket {
color: green;
}

.html-tag {
color: blue;
}

.html-attribute {
color: brown;
}

.html-attributeValue {
color: red;
}

.comment {
color: orange;
}

.css-selector {
color: blue;
}

.css-delimiter {
color: purple;
}

.css-property {
color: brown;
}

.css-propertyValue {
color: red;
}

.css-important {
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
}

.javascript {
color: black;
}

.javascript-string {
color: blue;
}

.javascript-keyword {
color: green;
}

.javascript-number {
color: red;
}

.javascript-property {
color: purple;
}

#colorCode, #code {
white-space: pre-wrap;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 15px;
overflow: auto;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
border: 1px solid black;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

#colorCode {
user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div id="colorCode"></div>
<div id="code" oninput="syntaxHighlight(this, 'html'); syncScroll(this, this.previousElementSibling);" onscroll="syncScroll(this, this.previousElementSibling)" contentEditable="plaintext-only" spellcheck="false"></div>
</div>
```