# Change word color in input or textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

For a chat app, I need to change the color of words starting with a special character, `@word` inside an input tag, i.e:

> Hello @John how are you?

the part `@John` should **change color** inside the input, i.e:

> Hello **@John** how are you?

It works after it's posted, but that's obviously another code. I want it to highlight words (*@mention*) by changing its color right in the input or textarea Element.

Comment: You can't do this with <input> or <textarea> - if you are wanting to apply styles to the user input while it's still editable, you'll need to look into the ````contenteditable```` attribute, which lets other elements be editable - and then you can control what happens with them using js.

Comment: What decides that the @ condition no longer persists? Is it just a space, or any non-alphanumeric character or.....

Comment: One way to do this might be with TinyMCE [enter link description here](https://www.tiny.cloud)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'd accept calling it "difficult" to implement, but I don't think it would be "unreliable" if done properly. At least the cases you list are all trivial to solve for this limited application. Besides, if you're after "reliability", your answer only *barely* works for even the very narrow case in the question. Even a) wanting to make the @ name bold, would cause a glitch, and b) it can't handle text longer than the input size width. It broke from typing a few letters. By the time it's a "reliable" solution, it will probably be as life-sucking as the alternative!

Comment: @Snor I agree, a) bold cannot be used since it's different text width in non-monospace font family. (So the solution would be to use one). b) seems to be fixed by using a textarea in where we can determine the scrollLeft position and transfer/mirror it to the underlying PRE tag.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ah, cool! I was thinking that would be tricky with <input>, but a <textarea> to give scrolling properties is a good solution there. And it is a pretty neat answer overall! :) One standard interaction that doesn't work is when you try to scroll with the mouse selection due to overflow: hidden. I suppose instead of overflow-x being hidden, the scrollbar could be outside the parent element, and hide that overflow instead. Or otherwise scrollbar to 0/none would work if you're happy with current prefixes/compatibility! (And then a scroll event to update the text too, I guess)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Probably needs an input event check on the contents too already actually, to stop multi-line content being pasted in. These things do get out of control quickly, haha...

Comment: @Snor yeah, I just started to dig under my feet with that answer. I'm reviewing actively all your suggestions. a) yes, text-highlight does not auto-scroll as it would be expected. b) "paste" event should have a separate listener to handle the newlines in the incoming data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Color specific text inside a textarea-*alike* element

One [5y old idea (Highlight syntax in contenteditable)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41885674/383904) would be to:

let the user type into a **contenteditable** DIV with **transparent color** but **visible caret**, then get and modify the content on the fly as-you-ype to an underlying DIV, used as a *markup* highlighter.

Basically:

- On *"input"* event get the editable innerHTML, do some `String.prototype.replace()` with a [regular expression that matches *@mentions*](https://regex101.com/r/TY4DM3/1) on the contenteditable  *value* and replace i.e: `@John` with `<span class="mention">@John</span>`
- Write the result as HTML to the underlying (highlighter) DIV element.

This way you're not replacing and creating any child `SPAN` elements in the area where the user is typing, but actually on the underlying one.

```js
const colorMention = (elText, elPre) => {
  elPre.innerHTML = elText.innerHTML.replace(/(?<=^| )@\p{L}+/gu, "<span class='mention'>$&</span>");
};

const scrollMirror = (elText, elPre) => {
  elPre.scrollTo(elText.scrollLeft, elText.scrollTop);
};

const handleKey = (ev, elText, elPre) => {
  if (ev.key === "Enter" && !ev.shiftKey) {
    // prevent Enter key behavior (new-line)
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Check message to send...
    const message = elText.innerHTML;
    if (!message.trim()) {
      return; // Nothing to submit. Message is empty
    }

    // YOUR SUBMIT LOGIC GOES HERE:
    console.log(message);

    // Clear fields:
    elText.innerHTML = "";
    elPre.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    // Any other key: (scroll areas is necessary)
    scrollMirror(elText, elPre);
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll(".message").forEach(el => {

  const elText = el.querySelector(".text");
  const elPre = el.querySelector(".pre");

  elText.addEventListener("scroll", () => scrollMirror(elText, elPre));
  elText.addEventListener("keyup", () => scrollMirror(elText, elPre));
  elText.addEventListener("input", () => colorMention(elText, elPre));
  elText.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => handleKey(ev, elText, elPre));

  // Init:
  colorMention(elText, elPre);
  scrollMirror(elText, elPre);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px/1.3 sans-serif;
}

.message {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.message .pre,
.message .text {
  border: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 5rem;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


/* The overlay contenteditable with transparent text but visible caret */

.message .text {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  /* transparent color */
  color: transparent;
  /* but visible caret */
  caret-color: black;
}


/* The underlaying element with colors */

.message .pre {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Prevent text selections */
  user-select: none;
}

.mention {
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  <div class="pre"></div>
  <div class="text" contenteditable spellcheck="false">Hi @Roko, how are you today?</div>
</div>

<br>
Chat tips:<br> Use <code>@username</code> to mention a user.<br> Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to send.<br> Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to a new line.<br>
```

Regarding the **regular expression** for **matching mentions**:

```js
/(?<=^| )@\p{L}+/gu
```

here's a [Regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/TY4DM3/1)  with description, and a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74083312/383904).

---

Comment: This seems to fail when I edit the contents of the input field: the highlighted @Daniel no longer sits where it should. For example, place the cursor between "H" and "i" and start typing spaces.

Comment: It's actually a great solution. The only issue it brings is that when the value inside the input is longer than the width of the box, will the text overlap. No overflow element will react to it really.

Comment: Incredible work! Works like a charm. It comes with one other issue though. When it was an input, then I could hit "Enter" to post. Now that it's a textarea it wants to break lines which your JS obviously rejects, but it will not post anything. Simply nothing happens at all. For a chat function (which this will mainly be used for) is it really nice to be able to press ENTER and not a button in order to post the form.

Comment: @DanielTenan At the end (since I encountered inconsistencies that are way hard to resolve related to the `textarea` element scroll-reflect) I ended up using the  `contenteditable` like I did 5y ago :)